# iOS multitasking for an Audio Recording application

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio

I am writing an application that records audio. I am looking into the feasibility of supporting multitasking while doing audio recordings (in the background).

The answer seems to be a *no* from what I've read so far, especially since the program is meant to release any system resources being used when switched out.

So I am wondering, is it possible to let the user switch to another application in iOS while my application continues to capture audio in the background?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do the same thing. Did you do as tc said and set it to both "voip" and "audio"? Have you succeeded in the recording?

Comment: @Namratha Don't set it to voip if you're not a voip provider. Our app got rejected because of that. Recording in the background was not a bad thing to do as it turns out. The OS is aware since you're hooked to the AVAudioSession. Just used it as it was and everything was fine.

Comment: Oh. Thanks a lot for the advice. So the background audio recording worked? Great! How exactly did you do it, please?

Comment: @Namratha Nothing special. iOS handles everything in the background... write your app as if it is recording in the foreground. When you go to the background, just stop all your timers that shows time elapsed etc. Recording will continue to happen. The user get this glowing red bar on top as it is being recorded (with your app name on it). If you want to know how to do recordings please refer to AVAudioRecorder class or AudioQueue API ;)

Comment: @Dineth: Which callback are you using to know when the application has gone to the background? I know how to do the recording, thanks :)Is this background mode possible only in iOS4? Also, does iOS limit your background recording time? Or will the app show a consistent behaviour ie record till out of memory(as the case in foreground recording)?

Comment: I unchecked the box in the Info.plist file that says "Application does not run in background" and also added the <key>UIBackgroundModes</key><array><string>audio</string></array> in Info.plist. But, the recording stops as soon as I press the 
"HOME" button. Please help.

Comment: Audio Recording in background is possible.There are many app in iTunes which allow continuous recording of the voice while the app remains in background. I'm also working on this but still could not find any sample code.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can. Skype does this.

You presumably need to set `<key>UIBackgroundModes</key><array><string>audio</string></array>` in Info.plist, and you need to make sure that the audio session is active/running/whatever before you switch apps (the assumption is that you won't suddenly start recording/playing music/whatever when your app is in the background).

[The docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) say that "audio" lets you play audio in the background, but presumably this also applies to recording audio. If it doesn't work, there are a few things you could try:

- Set both "voip" and "audio".
- Play silence (this might be easiest to do with the Audio Queue API).

Comment: "presumably this also applies to recording audio" -- in my experience, those are the kinds of assumptions on which you don't want to make a business decision.

Comment: Just wanted to update this answer. Do not use VOIP if your app isn't doing VOIP. It is there to enable network activity while the app is in the background. Using "audio" does the trick. Our app got rejected on the first go for having voip.

Answer (score 5):

Apple appears to have been accepting apps for iOS4 which continue to record audio when put in the background, so this may be an existence proof.  The app has to declare itself as background audio capable, pre-allocate all audio resources and start the audio recording before the app gets backgrounded, and also expect to get killed if its memory or audio resources are required by the foreground app.  So any use of system resources should be the absolute minimum.

Comment: Not if declared in the plist as 1 of the 3 special types for backgrounding, and sufficient resources are available.

Comment: That's great news!  You don't happen to have a link on this do you?

Comment: Look for UIBackgroundModes audio in Apple's documentation on UIKit Keys.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

Your app will continue recording/playing an audio while it is sent to background.

Do not try to use VOIP unless you don't wish to publish your app to apple store (say you will broadcast your app using third party stores who install provisioning profile).