# Get Microphone Permission when Phone is Locked

Tags: android, ios, permissions, lockscreen

I'd love to know if there is any way for an app to be recording the microphone/camera input when the screen is locked, granted proper permissions given by the user. The question is valid for both Android and iOS (both native).

Cheers!

Comment: in iOS its not possible

Comment: In android if you have the camera permission and nobody else is using the camera it doesn't matter if the phone is locked or not.

Comment: Make sure not to peak into others privacy.

Comment: Thanks for the answers Shobhakar and Gabe!
Shobhakar after some more search, seems like iOS permits such a thing (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918761/avaudiorecorder-doesnt-record-while-screen-is-locked), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477958/avaudiorecorder-stops-when-lock-button-is-pressed?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848172/ios-multitasking-for-an-audio-recording-application?noredirect=1&lq=1) - not sure if still relevant).
user6657161 agreed, there are lots of responsabilities for such a power.