# CADislayLink does not trigger if device is locked

Tags: ios, triggers, sleep, cadisplaylink

EDIT: Using `CADislayLink` to monitor the `AVAudioRecorder` meters is not a good idea if app run in background. It stops triggering if device sleeps (in my case is locking the device). The solution for that is using `NSTimer` instead. Here is the code which cause my issue

```
- (void)startUpdatingMeter {
    // Using `CADisplayLink` here is not a good choice. It stops triggering if lock the device
    self.meterUpdateDisplayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleAudioRecorderMeters)];
    [self.meterUpdateDisplayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}
```

Solution: using NSTimer instead

```
  // Set timeInterval as frame refresh interval
  self.timerMonitor = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.f/60.f target:self selector:@selector(handleAudioRecorderMeters:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
  [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.timerMonitor forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

The code below is working perfect with `AVAudioRecorder`, no matter we're using `AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord` or `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`.

ORIGINAL QUESTION: So far I'm creating an application that records sound, even it's in background mode. It's quite like [iTalk](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/italk-recorder/id293673304?mt=8).

Everything is nearly perfect, my app can record while is foreground / background (by registering background mode - [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)), but it pauses/stops if device is locked (by user or by self-device).

I tried iTalk and it works fine in that case. I also get a hint from iTalk: it has music control on lock screen, while my app does not have.

[image]

Here is my code to config `AVAudioSession` and `AVAudioRecorder`

```
- (void)configurateAudioSession {
    NSError *error = nil;
    // Return success after set category
    BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers error:&error];
    // Return success after set active
    success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];
    // Return success after set mode
    success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVideoRecording error:&error];
}

- (void)configAudioRecorder {
    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath_ = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pathToSave = [documentPath_ stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString]];

    // Create audio recorder
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToSave];
    NSDictionary *settings = @{ AVSampleRateKey: @44100.0,
                                AVFormatIDKey: @(kAudioFormatAppleLossless),
                                AVNumberOfChannelsKey: @1,
                                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey:@(AVAudioQualityMax), };

    NSError *error = nil;
    self.audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error on create audio: %@", error);
    }
    else {
        [self.audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
        self.audioRecorder.meteringEnabled  = YES;
        [self.audioRecorder record];
    }
}
```

I would be very grateful if you could provide me with any information. Thank guy!

Comment: Take note that CADisplayLink is more adapted to UI proceccing and synchronised with the MainRunLoop.
NSTimer might result in performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the category of your `AVAudioSession` like this

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:&sessionError];
```

So that it will record the audio when the device is locked.

**As the doc says**

> To continue recording audio when your app transitions to the
>   background (for example, when the screen locks), add the audio value
>   to the UIBackgroundModes key in your information property list file.

Also check this link

[AVAudioRecorder doesn't record while screen is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918761/avaudiorecorder-doesnt-record-while-screen-is-locked)

Comment: I'm afraid that it does not change anything. `AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord` and `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` have the same result, as I tell above

Comment: I dont understand why it will not work, as docs says it will work while screen is lock.

Comment: You're right. The recorder still works under device-locking. The problem comes from CADisplayLink, which I use to monitor the recorder. I'll update on my question. Thank a lot!

Comment: I think it will be better if you post a new question, then it will be on top and most of the user can see it.(Just a suggestion)

Comment: Ah, actually I found the issue and fixed it. So I think it might better if updating on my question instead of create a new one.

Comment: No problem. Go for it,