# iphone AVAudioRecorder, record audio in thread

Tags: ios, nsthread, nsoperation, avaudiorecorder

I now how to record a sound in iOS, but it decreases the performance of my app. It's possible to record the sound in a new thread? how?

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848172/ios-multitasking-for-an-audio-recording-application)
Possible duplicate btw

Comment: than tag with [GCD](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html), [NSOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html), [NSThread](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html) .. You can also take a look at those classes yourself too

Answer (score 2):

Audio Recording is handled directly by the hardware codec so should not impact CPU based activities. Putting it in a thread will make no difference

Have you profiled your App to figure out what is causing the slowdown. For example are you using a complex Mic input level display and blocking the main thread there.

Have a look at your recording options and figure out if this is affecting the performance

This is the setup I use for simultaneous drawing and recording in my app. It works fine on an iPad1 which has a dog of a CPU

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error: &setCategoryError];
    if (setCategoryError){
        NSLog(@"Error setting category! %@", [setCategoryError localizedDescription]);
        return NO;
    }


    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:5];

    [options setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey]; //format
    [options setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; //sample rate 
    [options setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey]; //channels
    //encoder 
    [options setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityHigh] forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey]; //channels
    [options setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVEncoderBitDepthHintKey]; //channels

self.audiorecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:mediaURL settings:options error:&error];
self.audiorecorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
```

Im sceptical about the recording in itself slowing down your drawing.