# How to display red status on home screen on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, notifications, status

I'm making an app which is a counter.

I would like to show the time when the user enters the home screen as it is shown here:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8455739/SCR/IMG_2696.PNG

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8455739/SCR/IMG_2697.PNG

Is it possible to use it? If yes, where to find it and how to use it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What part of that do you wish to ape - the red bar, the count up, or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the content of the home screen.

What you can do that you display such a status bar inside your application.
The exampels you showed, have such a bar inside an application.

To create such a bar you create a custom View (see Apple ViewProgramming Guide) 
where you implement `drawRect()`.
In drawRect you draw a red rectangle with CGFillRect() or similar methods of CoreGraphics / Quartz2D.

Answer (score 0):

You should use VOIP in Background or recording audio.
Check this [LINK voip](http://blog.toshsoft.de/index.php?/archives/4-Adding-Background-Audio-and-VoIP-to-your-iPhone-App.html) and [LINK audio recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848172/ios-multitasking-for-an-audio-recording-application)

Comment: I think you cannot use for timer that way.